# Vs Code Extension API how to get setting's from remote container?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a devcontainer, vscode settings can optionally be added to the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file instead of `settings.json`.

```
// devcontainer.json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": {
        "myextension.exclude": [
          "**/.git*", 
          "**/node_modules", 
        ]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

How can I access these values from the extension API? I know I can get the workspace settings with:

```
let setting = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myextension.exclude');
```

I've been unable to locate any documentation on dealing with extensions in remote containers.

When looking at the Settings UI, remote containers show up as a separate tab from workspace/user.

[image]

Comment: which values do you get when you fetch the settings?

Comment: It appears that if `settings.json` doesn't define that property, then it will get it from my `.devcontainer` settings. If `settings.json` does define it then thats what it returns. My exclude list is an array and ideally I'd like to get it from both and merge them together.

Comment: VSC will do the merging for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration` API returns a `WorkspaceConfiguration`, which *merges* the information from different levels, according to the documentation:

```js
     /**
     * Represents the configuration. It is a merged view of
     *
     * - *Default Settings*
     * - *Global (User) Settings*
     * - *Workspace settings*
     * - *Workspace Folder settings* - From one of the {@link workspace.workspaceFolders Workspace Folders} under which requested resource belongs to.
     * - *Language settings* - Settings defined under requested language.
     *
     * The *effective* value (returned by {@linkcode WorkspaceConfiguration.get get}) is computed by overriding or merging the values in the following order:
     *
     * 1. `defaultValue` (if defined in `package.json` otherwise derived from the value's type)
     * 1. `globalValue` (if defined)
     * 1. `workspaceValue` (if defined)
     * 1. `workspaceFolderValue` (if defined)
     * 1. `defaultLanguageValue` (if defined)
     * 1. `globalLanguageValue` (if defined)
     * 1. `workspaceLanguageValue` (if defined)
     * 1. `workspaceFolderLanguageValue` (if defined)
     *
     * **Note:** Only `object` value types are merged and all other value types are overridden.
     ...
```

It doesn't say anything about *remotes*, but *I guess* that the setting defined in `devcontainer.json` is equivalent to *Workspace Folder settings*.

But your code has a small mistake. You must use dotted notation while dealing with settings. So, in fact, the source code should be:

```js
    let setting = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myextension').get('exclude');
```

Just a side note, if you need to load some specific *level / view* of your setting, you should use the `inspect` method instead of `get`, but I don't think this is your case.

Hope this helps

Comment: I actually was originally trying to get the setting from settings and merge them since my setting is an array, but have since decided I should just let settings.json override it. Knowing about `inspect` for future projects will be handy though so thanks for that tidbit!! Helps a lot with understanding this API